# how to verify if checkbox is checked in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i would like to implement some code under the condition checkbox is checked or not, here is my code:

```
CheckBox checkBox=findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
  if(checkBox.isChecked()){
        Log.v("checked","true");
        spin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        montant2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtVw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            auth3();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

normally i should be able to view the log inside the if condition but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Check Box checked by default? when does the code run?
you're only printing a log when the checkBox is checked, but you won't get any log if the statement is false.

Try to add this line before your if statement:

```
checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

If you're getting the log after adding this line, it means that your checkbox is not checked when running the code.

**EDIT:**

You're running the code in the OnCreate method where the checkBox.getChecked() is set to false by default. To make it work, you need to create a listener that will run the code every time that the checkBox is checked.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                // Everytime you check the checkBox, the following code will execute:
                // Your code here //
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: the checkbox is not checked by default @tuvel

Comment: @RamsesKouam where do you run the code? after you checked the checkBox?

Comment: i run in the onCreate method and and tried your code, and the log is shown

Comment: @RamsesKouam Please look at the new edit on my answer. It may solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Log, you can use one **boolean variable** to identify like:

```
 Boolean checkbox = false;
 CheckBox checkBox=findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
 if(checkBox.isChecked()){
    checkbox = true;
 }else{
    checkbox = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
public void itemClicked(View yourView) {
      CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)yourView;
      if(checkBox.isChecked()){
    
      }
    }
```